# Homeserver DNS issue

Tags: networking, dns, port

I am running a little homeserver on my raspberry pi which runs a few simple apps which I intend to access from outside and within the actual network. In order to do that I registered an Domain at no-ip and forwarded the corresponding ports. Now comes the tricky thing:

How do I get all devices within my home network to resolve the registered domain to my local homenetwork address '192.168.2.XXX' when they are in the home network? For Windows this is quite simply done by editing the hosts file but this is a non flexible solution and I would also like to get this to work on mobile android devices, and my other linux system.

For my router I am using an EasyBox-904 if that is any important.

Can someone please ellaborate on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use local dns resolver for connection inside your home network. The example for huawei router in attach.

[image: Static dns config on huawei router]

Or try to enable nat-loopback in port forwarding configuration if you router supports that feature.

Comment: wow looks like my router is in fact the only model they developed for which they refused implementing nat loopback. now i got to get another router just for that kind of stuff to work